# Easy question-a linear functional mapped as the summation of unit vectors equals n?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, analysis, multivariable-calculus

So I'm trying to provide a counterexample for a problem I'm working on from topology; the problem is not relevant here and will not help with my question, but it has to do with continuous functions and open sets mapping onto open sets.  So I decided to get fancy with it by mapping a function from $\mathbb{R} ^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(\vec{x})=f(x_1,...,x_n)=\frac{x_1}{|x_1|}+...+\frac{x_n}{|x_n|}$. Should this equal n? My linear algebra is a bit rusty

Comment: Answer yes iff $x$ has all its coordinates positive. No need for linear algebra.

Comment: oh right, that makes sense. Thank you for the confirmation!

Comment: Wait, somethings off here. Shouldn't I also take the magnitude of these unit vectors as well, so that they are scalars? i.e. $|\frac{x_1}{|x_1|}|$

Comment: Aren't the $x_i$ just real numbers, not unit vectors?

Comment: Yes, that finally clicked after pondering for a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Each $\frac{x_1}{|x_1|}$ is equal to $1$ is $x_i \geq 0$ or $-1$ otherwise.

The only way a sum of $n$ numbers each one with value $\pm1$ can be equal to $n$ is that we are, for each $i$ in the case $+1$, which means that all the $x_i$ should be positive.